# How can I import several taxonomy term values into a single term_reference field using the feeds module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, feed, drupal-taxonomy

I'm using the feeds module on a drupal 7 instance and I have a content type with a term_reference field with the option to include multiple tags. My question is, how can I import multiple tags from a CSV file with the feeds module? I tried by adding more sources for the same target, terms are created on the database but only the last one remains on the created nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Feeds tamper module to add explode function to mapper and map EACH entry(in this case, separate multiple values for single field by a pipe or similar).